# Почему отсутствуют компоненты DevExprees Winforms?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Создаю простой проект на Win Forms с компонентами от DevExpress ,но в дизайнере отсутствуют котролы от DevExpress . Как можно это исправить ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть приблизительно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В меню `DevExpress` должна кнопка `Repair Toolbox...`

Comment: Не помогло. Я ещё патч скачал ,который вроде фиксит эту проблему, но он не помог

Comment: Тогда попробуйте запустить инсталлятор и нажать на `Repair`.

Comment: Убедитесь что версия .net framework выбранная в проекте - 4.0 и выше Кроме того, эта кнопка (Repair Toolbox), так же собирает диагностическую информацию, по которой техническая поддержка может сразу же сказать что не так с Visual Studio и как решить проблему. Эти логи нужно отправлять на support@devexpress.com или через официальный канал технической поддержки: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/. Отвечают оперативно.